# Google App Engine - org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Object Manager has been closed

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, jpa, datanucleus

Why does the code below result in org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Object Manager has been closed? The exception appears to be thrown at query.getResultList().

```
public final void removeUserTokens(final String username) {
    final Query query = entityManager.createQuery(
        "SELECT p FROM PersistentLogin p WHERE username = :username");
    query.setParameter("username", username);

    for (Object token : query.getResultList()) {
        entityManager.remove(token);
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Object Manager has been closed
 at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.assertIsOpen(ObjectManagerImpl.java:3876)
 at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.getFetchPlan(ObjectManagerImpl.java:376)
 at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.getFetchPlan(Query.java:497)
 at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.query.DatastoreQuery$6.apply(DatastoreQuery.java:611)
 at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.query.DatastoreQuery$6.apply(DatastoreQuery.java:610)
 at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.query.LazyResult.resolveNext(LazyResult.java:94)
 at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.query.LazyResult$LazyAbstractListIterator.computeNext(LazyResult.java:215)
 at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.query.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:132)
 at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.query.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:127)
 at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.query.LazyResult$AbstractListIterator.hasNext(LazyResult.java:169)
 at com.mystuff.service.auth.PersistentTokenRepositoryImpl.removeUserTokens(PersistentTokenRepositoryImpl.java:90)
```

**Edit**: I increased the log level for datanucleus and this is what I see.

```
FINE: Object Manager "org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@5d8d3d6c" opened for datastore "org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastoreManager@2447e380"
Feb 25, 2010 7:21:38 AM org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl initialiseLevel1Cache
FINE: Level 1 Cache of type "weak" initialised
Feb 25, 2010 7:21:38 AM org.datanucleus.JDOClassLoaderResolver classForName
FINE: Class "java.lang.PersistentLogin" was not found in the CLASSPATH [Class resolver called from org.datanucleus.util.Imports.resolveClassDeclaration (line=177)]
Feb 25, 2010 7:21:38 AM org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl disconnectSMCache
FINE: Level 1 Cache cleared
Feb 25, 2010 7:21:38 AM org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl postClose
FINE: Object Manager "org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@5d8d3d6c" closed
Feb 25, 2010 7:21:38 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: /j_spring_security_logout
Object Manager has been closed
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Object Manager has been closed
 at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.assertIsOpen(ObjectManagerImpl.java:3876)
 at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.getFetchPlan(ObjectManagerImpl.java:376)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `@Transactional` to the method prevents the object manager from closing. However, I'm not sure why it closes without this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why exactly, but it seems to have to do with `query.getResultList()` being lazy-loaded. Apparently the lazy-loading breaks down when you call `remove(token)`.

As a work-around can you collect the ids/keys for the elements in an ArrayList first, and in a separate loop remove them from the datastore?

Comment: Hmmm, the exception is thrown at getResultList() so collecting the ids/keys would still require a getResultList() call which I assume would fail. I feel like I have a larger problem going on that's related to the way Spring and GAE are interacting.

Comment: the difference is that loading the instances (which happens when you iterate over the result list in Iterator.hasNext(), not in getResultList()) would not be interleaved with the remove() calls.

Answer (score 0):

the solution that worked for me and a description of the bug i found here:

http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/945f6ca66c1c587e