# Saving many entities in GAE with JPA

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, entity

I'm using JPA with with Google App Engine. 
Let's say I have a very simple @Entity consisting of a Key and a String, nothing more. I now create 10000 of these entities, put them in a list and now want to store all of them.

If I try to use an EntityManager *em* and a for loop to go through the *List* of all my entities...

```
for(MyEntity entity : listOfAllEntities) {
 em.persist(entity);
}
```

.. I will get an IllegalArgumentException:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't operate on multiple entity groups in a single transaction.

As far as I understand it, I need to close and reopen the EntityManager for each persist() call. Of course, this is very time consuming.
I'm trying to have a task running once a day that reloads all the entities. According to GAE policy, the task has a timeout of 30 seconds.

So an alternative is to only save 500 entities at a time and run the task multiple times which I think is more complicated than it has to be.

Is this the only way of achieving what I'm trying to do or am I missing something here?

**Solution:**
All the answers point in the same direction. I simply created a One-To-Many relationship by creating a "dummy parent" entity. I don't really need a parent in my case and it doesn't make much sense in the real world so to speak. But after setting this dummy entity as parent of each of the child entities, I can save them exactly as I did before without caring too much about transactions. Thanks to all.

Comment: [Read the answer to this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323777/google-app-engine-cant-operate-on-multiple-entity-groups-in-a-single-transacti). It sounds like the same issue that you are having.

Comment: Yeah, that was my question. I fixed it by adding a parent entity and then having an owned one-to-many relationship so they were in the same entity group.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Not sure if I can apply the chosen answer in my case but I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Wow that's bizarre. Good question and answer.

Comment: @socken23 Sorry i got same error. can you show some code snippet how to make that? i trying to update a list of entity which is extending from 1 parent class but it still got error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this is oversimplified, but you could just add the X number of entities as children of a parent entity and this would cause them to be in the same entity group. This would allow you to persist them all in one transaction. Basically, create an owned one-to-many relationship between the parent entity and the children which are the objects you are trying to persist.

Comment: Interesting, so I could basically just create a "dummy" parent for all my entities and save them exactly like I'm trying to now? Will also try that, thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Children with a common parent will be in the same entity group.

Comment: Don't put a lot of Entities in the same Entity Group if you don't need transactions. This can make your app very slow.

Comment: Peter makes a good point. It depends on if you really need transactions or not.

Answer (score 1):

This error says that you use transaction and trying to operate on multiple entity groups.

From docs:

> All datastore operations in a transaction must operate on entities in the same entity group. This includes querying for entities by ancestor, retrieving entities by key, updating entities, and deleting entities. Notice that each root entity belongs to a separate entity group, so a single transaction cannot create or operate on more than one root entity.

You can't just create more than one root (without parent) entity in transaction, but you can do it if each of them are child of another entity. If you want just to create entities — do it outside of transaction.

Comment: This is a good point. It depends on if @socken23 really needs this to be transactional or not. If not, then not using a transaction like you suggest would work fine.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense now. I will try to save them outside of a transaction then. Guess I do have some reading to do first. I didn't read a lot on the topic yet and will have to do that in order to see where GAE uses transactions automatically.