# How to iterate JPA collections in Google App engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, datanucleus

I use Google App Engine with datanucleus and JPA. I'm having a real hard time grasping how I'm supposed to read stuff from data store and pass it to JSP. If I load a list of POJOs with entitymanager and pass it to JSP, it crashes to org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Object Manager has been closed.

I understand why this is happening. Obviously because I fetch the list, close the entity manager and pass it to JSP, at which point it will fail because the list is lazy. How do I make the list *NOT* lazy without resorting to hacks like calling size() or something like that?

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    req.setAttribute("parties", getParties());
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/parties.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(req, resp);
}

private List<Party> getParties(){
    EntityManager em = entityManagerProvider.get();
    try{
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Party p");
        return query.getResultList();
    }finally{
        em.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294867/google-app-engine-org-datanucleus-exceptions-nucleususerexception-object-manag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/576930e42eaf4819/634233996a2466e8), *DataNucleus itself provides mechanisms for reading in of query
results when a transaction commits. It's likely just not yet implemented in the plugin yet*. This is reported in [Issue 24](http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/issues/detail?id=24) and until this issue get solved, my understanding is that you'll have to either call `size()` to load the list or to use the `OpenEntityManagerInView` pattern.

Comment: Thanks, although I'm going to use new LinkedList(results) or new ArrayList(results) on this, because it feels conceptually more right to me than just calling size(). Atleast this way I can control what kind of collection I actually get from the query.

I could use OpenEntityMangerInView pattern, but it feels so overkill solution for such a simple problem. Maybe if the software grows in size.